# Can't center UIScrollView around CGPoint on y axis, or when zoomed

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I am trying to center a CGPoint inside the Visible Rectangle that is my UIScrollView.

Here is the setup:

[image]

I have a SpriteKit scene with some objects on it. This scene is basically the View for my UIScrollView. The Scene is much larger than the visible scene on the device, as show with the visible rectangle.

**I want to set the contentOffset of the UIScrollView so that a point is in the center of the visible rect.**

[image]

Here is what I have tried doing, to no avail:

```
    CGPoint adjustment = CGPointMake(visibleRect.size.width/2, visibleRect.size.height/2);
    CGPoint wantedMidPoint = node.position;

    CGPoint newOffset = CGPointMake(wantedMidPoint.x - adjustment.x, wantedMidPoint.y + adjustment.y);
```

The Offset is then set as follows:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:newOffset animated:YES];
```

The problem is this does not work. What specifically? The Y Position.

In each case, the selected node *does* get centered. However, the Y coordinate is totally screwy. If I add the adjustment, it goes up or down *inversely* to what I want it to. If I subtract it, it totally flies off screen. I don't know how to fix this.

**Also**, if I zoom a little, the X position gets flung off track too. I don't understand why. I've tried scaling the offset adjustment up or down based on the scaling, but it doesn't help.

This wasn't my only attempt. I've tried using the visible rect of the UIScrollView this way too:

```
[scrollView convertRect:scrollView.bounds
                             toView:[scrollView.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView]];
```

If someone could explain how to do this, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it eventually. It's some awfully screwy behavior with the way the coordinate system worked.

My eventual solution was as follows:

```
CGPoint midPoint = [self convertPoint:(CGPoint){self.visibleRect.size.width/2,-self.visibleRect.size.height/2} toNode:self.sceneNode];

CGVector adjustment = (CGVector){node.position.x - midPoint.x, node.position.y - midPoint.y};
```

Basically, I had to use the *negative* height to get the middle Y coordinate of the visible scene in the background. And that's it. This also fixed the scaling issue.

If you are having a similar problem. I would suggest using trial and error by adding a Sprite or some sort of visible indicator at where you believe the midpoint should be. Keep adjusting till you get it, and make sure it always displays this midpoint wherever you scroll. Then you can use the difference in your node and the midpoint to calculate the offset you need to center it.

Hope this helps someone.